# Push component to array of components - ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am a bit lost in React arrays. What I want to do is to have array of components (articles) and in that array I want to have title and content.

What I want to do with that array is add, remove and display it on my page.

So what am I doing wrong? Also what is this action exactly called?

Code was from [ReactJS demos](http://yiminghe.me/learning-react/) and modified a little by me.

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

// Articles page

const Articles = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {article: [

      {'title': 'hello', 'content': 'hello hello'},
      {'title': 'hello1', 'content': 'hello hello1'},
      {'title': 'hello2', 'content': 'hello hello2'},
      {'title': 'hello3', 'content': 'hello hello3'}

    ]};
  },
  onAdd() {
    const newArticle =
      this.state.article.concat([window.prompt('Enter article')]);
      this.setState({article: newArticle});
  },
  onRemove(i) {
    const newArticle = this.state.article;
    newArticle.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({article: newArticle});
  },
  render() {
    const article = this.state.article.map((article, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={article} onClick={this.onRemove.bind(this, i)}>
          {article}
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">
            <p>Articles Page</p>

            <button onClick={this.onAdd}>Add Article</button>
              <br />
              <br />
                {title}
              <br />
              <br />
                {content}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

module.exports = Articles;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your render method there are no variables `title` and `content`, however there is variable `article` where you are creating list with articles, you should remove variable `title` and `content` from `render` and use `article`. I've refactored your code, and now it looks like this

```
const Articles = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { 
      articles: [
        {'title': 'hello', 'content': 'hello hello'},
        {'title': 'hello1', 'content': 'hello hello1'},
        {'title': 'hello2', 'content': 'hello hello2'},
        {'title': 'hello3', 'content': 'hello hello3'}
      ]
    };
  },

  onAdd() {
    const title = window.prompt('Enter article title');   
    const content = window.prompt('Enter article content');

    this.setState({
      articles: this.state.articles.concat({ title, content })
    });
  },

  onRemove(index) {
    this.setState({ 
      articles: this.state.articles.filter((e, i) => i !== index)
    });
  },

  render() {
    const articles = this.state.articles.map((article, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <h2>
            { article.title } 
            <span
              className="link" 
              onClick={ this.onRemove.bind(this, i) }
            >
             X
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p>{ article.content }</p>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">
            <p>Articles Page</p>
            <div>{ articles }</div>
            <button onClick={this.onAdd}>Add Article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/33632/)

Comment: Thanks a lot - finally a bit of code that I understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your render you are creating the rows of your list and you have assigned it to the const called 'article'. However your render is:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">
        <p>Articles Page</p>

        <button onClick={this.onAdd}>Add Article</button>
          <br />
          <br />
            {title}
          <br />
          <br />
            {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

There is no where you are rendering the 'article' created. You could replace {content} with {article}? As I have seen no declaration of content anywhere.

Also, just an aside, you have named so many variables as 'article'. It's a bit hard to follow, might help pluralizing in some cases (but this does not relate to the question asked -:) )