# ReactJS - Is it possible to render this dictionary (via map) when the keys can change?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

**Question** Is it possible to render a dictionary with a key (which isn't known until an algorithm is run) with a value that is an array, itself with a dictionary with unknown key-value pairs until an algorithm is run?

**Detailed information**

I have this dictionary:

```
var currentWorkers = = {EmployeesAtRestaurant :
            [{"James" : "Manager"},
            {"Jessica" : "Waiter"},
            {"Bob" : "Waiter"},
            {"Ben" : "Chef"}],
            
            EmployeesAtOffice :
            [{"Rebecca" : "Manager"},
            {"Nicole" : "Part-time Employee"},
            {"Robert" : "Full-time Employee"},
            {"Eric" : "Full-time Employee"}],
            
            EmployeesAtZoo :
            [{"Robert" : "Manager"},
            {"Naomi" : "Part-time Employee"},
            {"Jennifer" : "Full-time Employee"},
            {"Ken" : "Full-time Employee"}]}
```

And I want to render it on a page as below (mock up). It is to display employees of an organisation:

[image: MockUp Example]

**What I've tried**

1. I've read some previous answers on Stack ([Push component to array of components - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812562/push-component-to-array-of-components-reactjs)) of how to attempt this, but their dictionaries use a simple key and value pair, and since my key is not known (i.e I can't do dictionary.Organisation for example) I'm not able to do the above.
2. I've tried to remodel the dictionary into a model similar to the above, but then I lose a lot of the information above.

Frankly, I'm beginning to suspect my best option is to just remodel the dictionary at this point, if the above is too difficult to attempt.

Comment: maybe methods like `Object.entries` and `Object.keys` could help to iterate your data but  you are right the data should be re-structured

Comment: lastr2d2 - You're completely right, I've just restructured my data to make rendering easier now ... the above was just too much to think about.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I'm understanding your question: Are you talking about the [special prop called `key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)<sup>[1]</sup> that React uses for rendering?

If that's the case, the important thing is that each `key` is unique, but it doesn't necessarily have to be the same `key` that your algorithms are calculating.

If you don't have access to the results of your algorithm yet, but you still want to render the strings like in your screenshots, you'll need a different unique key to use while mapping.

The `map` function on Arrays sends the element as the first function parameter, [and the element's `index` as the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)<sup>[2]</sup>. Lots of places will warn you that `index` keys aren't the best. As far as I know, this is because if the order of the Array shifts then you lose the optimization that React is trying to provide you.

If `index` is the only unique data you've got, however, it's reasonable to consider using it. This is especially true if the data is coming from a static source, because you know that the order of the data isn't going to shift out from under you.

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Hi Reed, thanks for the help (and you understood my question perfectly)! Based on your links, it's helped me solidify this topic but given my dictionaries just ... a bit much, I went ahead and just rewrote the algorithm to change the data structure (so now I can actually use render them as per your links).